# Can't delete file from samba share + Solaris + ZFS

Tags: solaris, samba, zfs, cifs

My disk storage running on Solaris + ZFS and i can't delete a file from my cifs share. I tried from Windows + Solaris nothing works...
I was thinking someone is using the file and i close my cifs with (zfs set smbshare=off) nothing changed..

My file is:

> -rwxrwxrwx+ 1 root                 root                      31584256 Feb  9 14:34 'A. Test2017-02-09T020046.vib'*
>
> rm -rf 'A. Test2017-02-09T020046.vib''
>
> rm: cannot remove 'A. Test2017-02-09T020046.vib': Permission denied

I'm root, i have every possible permission on this system but even the root can't delete this file! How is this possible?

Edit: Maybe nbmand causing this problem?
The SMB protocol assumes mandatory locking, but UNIX traditionally uses advisory locking. The Oracle Solaris OS can be configured to use mandatory locking on a per mount basis by using the non-blocking mandatory locking (nbmand) mount option.

Comment: Can you post the output from `zfs get all filesystem`, where `filesystem` is your ZFS filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

Is it mounted as a read only filesystem? If not, my best guess is that perhaps you're using the vscan option on the dataset, and that a virus scanner has flagged it and the vscand service locked the file down.

Can you do something like `file 'A. Test2017-02-09T020046.vib'` to see if the file can be read.

Comment: I'd think a read-only filesystem would return `EROFS` with a "read-only filesystem" message.  See http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/boot/lib/libstand/strerror.c#57

Answer (score 0):

I still have no answer but i think "Veeam backup" locking the file someway.
After reboot OS im able to delete the file.. 
Problem solved with reboot but this is really bad thing for Storage!
I hope this problem will not repeat again.